# Struct inside a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have struct

```
struct Course{
  int cId;
  string courseName;
};
```

and I want to add students for each Course. I thought to define another struct in to struct Course like

```
struct Course{
      int cId;
      string courseName;
      struct Student{
         int sId;
         string studentName;
      };
    };
```

if I define struct like this how could I use it ? I have `Course * cptr = new Course[1];`
which for using the struct course.
How could I add Students to specified cId's ?

Comment: Nested structs? Why??? Is there any good reason to do that?

Comment: Add a member for the `struct` you have declared inside the other one.

Comment: You should have attended class when they taught arrays

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: You should have attended class when they taught standard containers.

Comment: @phresnel, if you read the original poster's comments to answers, you will see that there was no such class!

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Course
{
    // ...
    struct Student
    {
        int sId;
        string studentName;
    };
};
```

This defines a struct `Course` and another struct `Course::Student`, but `Course` does not instantiate any student (there is no member of `Course` which has a type `Student`).  If you want students to be a member of course, you need something like this:

```
struct Course
{
    // ...
    struct Student
    {
        int sId;
        string studentName;
    } student;
};
```

or

```
struct Course
{
    // ...
    struct Student
    {
        int sId;
        string studentName;
    } students[10];
};
```

Which would define a single student or an array of 10 students as members of `Course`, respectively.  (NOTE:  `std::vector` would be a better choice than a statically sized array)

Alternatively, you can declare `Student` as a struct *outside* of `Course`:

```
struct Student { ... };

struct Course
{
    // ...
    Student student;
    // or std::vector<Student> students;
    // or std::array<Student, 10> students;
    // or Student* students
};
```

Comment: but number of students could change the execution so, I should allocate memory dynamically. How could I do that ? instead of using student[10] ?

Comment: @mxyz You would use a pointer and allocated it using `new[]` (and deallocating using `delete[]`).  If that is your requirement, the last `// or` in my last example would be the method you would need to use - if you are not permitted to use `std::vector`.

Comment: For example I have cptr[1].cId (it is unique) for specified course if I want to add students to this course how could I use stedents ?

Comment: Assuming that `cptr[1]` is an instance of `Course`, It would be something like `cptr[1].students = new Student[SIZE]; cptr[1].students[0].sId = SOMEID;`

Answer (score 5):

Your `Course` does not contain a `Student`. It just defines a struct of that name, i.e. a type `Course::Student`. For a type to contain an *instance* of another type, you just have to declare a member variable:

```
struct Student { .... };

struct Course
{
  ....
  Student student;
};
```

If you want each course to hold more than one `Student`, then you can use a container. In the absence of more information, the best candidate for that is `std::vector`:

```
struct Course
{
  ....
  std::vector<Student> students;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is your friend, but if you are not allowed to use that, you can do:

```
struct Student {...}; // Implementation omitted for brevity...

struct Course
{
  Student *students_; // Use students_=new Student[num_students]; to allocate
                      // memory dynamically
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way:

```
struct Student
{
    int sId;
    string studentName;
};

struct Course
{
    int cId;
    string courseName;
    std::vector <Student> students;
};
```

This way you may write

```
Student s;
Course c;
c.students.push_back(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to divide this struct into two individual struct. Then you can initialize a student object in the Course struct. Or u can implement a function in Course struct to link with Student struct.